# Firebase Remote Config not updating values?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm setting up an AB test using Firebase Remote Config and I'm trying to get the app to print a value depending on which group it's in. But, the values aren't updating even though it says the values have been retrieved.

`AppDelegate`:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var remoteConfig:RCValues!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    self.remoteConfig = RCValues.sharedInstance

    return true
}
```

I have a `RCValues` file:

```
enum ValueKey: String {
    case pricing
}

class RCValues {

    static let sharedInstance = RCValues()
    var loadingDoneCallback: (() -> ())?
    var fetchComplete: Bool = false

    private init() {
        loadDefaultValues()
        fetchCloudValues()
    }

    func loadDefaultValues() {
        let appDefaults: [String: Any?] = [
            ValueKey.pricing.rawValue: "Control"
        ]
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(appDefaults as? [String: NSObject])
    }

    func fetchCloudValues() {
        let fetchDuration: TimeInterval = 0
        activateDebugMode()
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: fetchDuration) {
            [weak self] (status, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print ("Uh-oh. Got an error fetching remote values \(error)")
                return
            }

            RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activateFetched()
            print ("Retrieved values from the cloud!")
            self?.fetchComplete = true
            self?.loadingDoneCallback?()
        }
    }

    func activateDebugMode() {
        let debugSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configSettings = debugSettings
    }

    func string(forKey key: ValueKey) -> String {
        return RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()[key.rawValue].stringValue ?? ""
    }

}
```

Then I use the `pricing` value when I want to check what group the user is in:

```
let group = RCValues.sharedInstance.string(forKey: .pricing)
print("your group is: \(group)")
```

But no matter what I do, I always end up getting "Control" printed, which is the default value I've set in the `RCValues` file for `pricing`. If I set it to something else in that file, it prints that.

What am I doing wrong?